# How can I create a desktop shortcut or something similar with Qt Installer Framework on Linux?

Tags: linux, deployment, shortcut, execution, qt-installer

I'm currently trying to deploy a small application for Linux using linuxdeploy and the Qt Installer Framework.
Now the whole process of running linuxdeploy and creating my installer works fine and when I run the installer, it installs the following directory (as it should):

```
AppDir
-- AppRun
-- AppRun.wrapped
-- usr
   -- bin
      -- App
   -- lib
-- ... (some other stuff from the installation, log, maintenance tools etc.)
```

My question is basically: Is the user supposed to run the actual binary file in bin? Because of course AppRun.wrapped is also a link to that file and runs the application, but assuming the user knows nothing about that, how do I make it easier to run the application?

I know that the Qt Installer Framework can create a desktop shortcut on Windows, but what would be the equivalent of that for Linux and how do I create it?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but it's my first time deploying something on Linux and I couldn't find an answer so far.

Thanks in advance!